# MobiLink synchronization scripts generation

Tags: mysql, sqlanywhere, mobilink

I'm working with MySQL as a consolidated database and SQLAnywhere as a remote database. I'm trying to synchronize all data using MobiLink.

I've just successfully managed to run database synchronization from this tutorial: http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1056497. When MobiLink is synchronizing data all changes on the consolidated (MySQL) database are made through triggers (script with them is attached to this tutorial).

My question is: is there any way to generate script with all that triggers within Sybase Central or in any other fast way? When I create my own database schema, is writing all that scripts necessary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the MobiLink plug-in in Sybase Central to create a [synchronization model](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/mlstart/mg-about-model-mode-7782.html).

[Other ways to get help with SQL Anywhere and MobiLink.](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/sausinghelp/uh-findoutmore.html)